# What does the function CvPoint2D32f in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

```
CvPoint2D32f
```

I want to know what this function does, for example:

```
CvPoint2D32f center = cvPoint2D32f(src->width/2,src->height/2);
```

Comment: What about it do you not understand?

Comment: Can you add a bit more to your question? What needs explaining? What are you working on?

Comment: That other question is closed, and has no useful answers. Jesse's answer here is good, and this question seems perfectly valid

Answer (score 6):

OpenCV has a few different data structures for points (that is, x:y or x:y:z coordinates) and their name tells you what type of point it is.

This particular point is a 2D Point - so it has just X and Y coordinates, and they are 32-bit floating point values.  That's what the **32f** at the end means.  A 3D point that uses 32-bit floating point values would have **3D32f** at the end of the data type name.

See [this page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html) in the OpenCV reference documentation for more info.

Comment: To add a little more detail to this answer, CvPoint2D32f (with a capital C)  is a data type to hold a 2D floating point value. cvPoint2D32f (with a lowercase C)  is a function that creates those datatypes from a given X and Y value pair.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted sets the coordinates of a 2D point type as the center coordinates of some `src` data structure (eg `cv::Mat` or `CvMat`).